# Linear model with proportions as the dependent variable

Tags: regression, probability, references, linear, plm

I have a linear model where the dependent model is a proportion (or a probability).

I know I should probably use another type of model, and I am. I would still like to use also a linear model because the following website says "I’ve heard that between .3-.7 [should be fine]".

http://www.theanalysisfactor.com/proportions-as-dependent-variable-in-regression-which-type-of-model/

Does anyone know a better reference than this website for when it is okay to use a linear model to predict proportions?

(The book referenced in the website does not seem to contain anything about this.)

Comment: I don't know a reference, but in the case where the data come from (say) a logistic regression model or a probit regression model for example, the reasoning is obvious enough; it could be explained fairly simply.